# How to select the previous sibling using selenium css syntax

Tags: selenium

EG How do select the second div in this list if all I have is the id of the third?

```
<div></div>
<div>I want this</div>
<div id="i_know_this"></div>
```

[This](http://blog.infostretch.com/are-you-ready-to-use-css-selectors-with-selenium) Suggests that I could use tilde. eg css=#i_know_this ~ div but it is selecting the next sibling rather than the previous one. Also, the ::before selector doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector path does not give you the privilege to move backward in the DOM hierarchy in that case you will have to use XPath `//*[@id='i_know_this']/preceding-sibling::div[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **axe** library (**axe** is a CSS post-processor).

In this instance, the *immediate previous* **axe** selector is `?`.

(It's the opposite of `+` in conventional CSS).

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
height: 36px;
padding: 6px 12px;
line-height: 36px;
}

#i_know_this:hover ? div {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>Ignore me</div>
<div>I want this</div>
<div id="i_know_this">Hover me</div>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```